# Validating Attached Property in Property Change handler

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I am developing a custom control for Windows Phone 8, which is derived from `ItemsControl`, will have many child objects(another custom class). It needs to have an Attached Property `IsMinonAxis` which should be set only once by one of the child, and not more than once. So the below code will be a problem I want to avoid.

```
<WPGraphControl:GraphControl>
     <WPGraphControl:GraphLine GraphDataPoints="{Binding SpeedPoints}"  WPGraphControl:GraphControl.IsMinonAxis="True" />
     <WPGraphControl:GraphLine GraphDataPoints="{Binding AltitudePoints}" WPGraphControl:GraphControl.IsMinonAxis="True" />
</WPGraphControl:GraphControl>
```

The problem is attached properties are attached to child controls, and not to the parent. 
In the `PropertyCHangedCallback` (registered as part of `RegisterAttached` as part of `PropertyMetadata`) I can get the child object for which the property is being set, but I can't access the actual control instance (`this`) to be able to validate the whole collection of child controls as its a static method common across all instances .

One option I am thinking is to have another attached property (internal) which will be attached when the child controls are added, and then use that property to get to parent inside the callback, and fire the validation logic. It sounds like a overly complicated logic to me.

Could you please suggest what is the best way to handle situations like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to have a non-attached property on GraphControl that takes a Element to be used. Its been a while since I did WinPhone XAML, but in WPF this would look something like:

```
<wpgc:GraphControl MinorAxis="{Binding ElementName=Foo}">
    <wpgc:GraphLine x:Name="Foo" />
    <wpgc:GraphLine x:Name="Bar" />
</wpgc:GraphControl>
```

Since you can only assign a single value to the property, then this would ensure that only one is set.

Comment: Sure, this satisfies / simplifies my approach. Thank you for the suggestion. I would still like to know how to validate the entire collection of attached properties across all children's in one method as a response to a change to one.